# SQL sum and show row with non-existent sum values

Tags: mysql, sql

i have 2 tables : dt_user and dt_invoice.

```
**dt_members :**
id firstname
3   Salim
5   Sara
8   Julie

**dt_invoice**

user_id    amount_ht    period month  year 
   3          4950     04 2018  04    2018
   3          7200     10 2018  10    2018
   8         11000     10 2018  10    2018
   8          5500     11 2018  11    2018
   3          6750     11 2018  11    2018
   3          8700     12 2018  12    2018
   3          8800     01 2019  01    2019
   8          7500     01 2019  01    2019
   3          4950     02 2019  02    2019
   3          7550     03 2019  03    2019
```

I want to create a query joining the two table, but i want to show each user_id for **PERIOD** that there is in table dt_invoice.

```
**Expected results :**
user_id    amount_ht    period month  year 
   3          4950     04 2018  04    2018
   5            0      04 2018  04    2018  //non-existent record in dt_invoice
   8            0      04 2018  04    2018  //non-existent record in dt_invoice
   3          7200     10 2018  10    2018
   5            0      10 2018  10    2018  //non-existent record in dt_invoice
   8         11000     10 2018  10    2018
   8          5500     11 2018  11    2018
   5            0      11 2018  11    2018  //etc ...
   3          6750     11 2018  11    2018
   3          8700     12 2018  12    2018
   5            0      12 2018  12    2018
   8            0      12 2018  12    2018
   3          8800     01 2019  01    2019
   5            0      01 2019  01    2019
   8          7500     01 2019  01    2019
   3          4950     02 2019  02    2019
   5            0      02 2019  02    2018
   8            0      02 2019  02    2018
   3          7550     03 2019  03    2019
   5            0      03 2019  03    2018
   8            0      03 2019  03    2018
```

Thanks in advance for your help, i'm totally stuck ..

SQL datas available here : https://rextester.com/live/LBSEY76360

also in sqlfiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/728af3/1

Comment: at first sight it looks like you need to create a table which holds all combinations possible and left join with it or write a deliverd table (subquery) with cross join to generate all possible combinations and left join with it...

Comment: What he said. Also, see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: How to do that using sql ?

Comment: Do you have a table of dates? or a table of numbers?

Comment: Please give `CREATE TABLE` statements for both the tables. Or, better provide a DB Fiddle / SQL Fiddle.

Comment: "How to do that using sql " Make a better formatted example because the current formetted text will not be correctly imported in online text to SQL generators in db-fiddle/sqlfiddle.

Comment: SQL datas available here : https://rextester.com/live/LBSEY76360

Comment: data also available here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/728af3/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `cross join` to generate the rows and `left join` to bring in the values:

```
select m.user_id, p.period, p.month, p.year,
       coalesce(t.amount_ht, 0) as amount_ht
from dt_members m cross join
     (select distinct period, month, year from dt_invoice) p left join
     dt_invoice t
     on t.user_id = m.id and t.period = p.period;
```

Comment: @user3206066 . . . Such a comment is very vague and provides no help.  How does it not work?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this would help.

```
SELECT user_id, amount_ht, period, month, year
FROM dt_invoice 
LEFT JOIN dt_members ON user_id = id
```